# Do I have to make a script to make an authorization header for jwt?

Tags: javascript, jwt

I am working on a simple website using jwt. (node.js, koa.js)
Most example codes including expressjs, I cannot find the client-side example 
about how to deal with jwt sent from a server.

Only one example (https://github.com/auth0-blog/cookie-jwt-auth) showed me that

[index.html]

... script src="app.js...

[app.js]

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/secured/authorize-cookie',
    data: {
        token: token
    },
    headers: {
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
    }
```

After I read this example, I felt that I should have some scripts for users to send an authorization header with jwt. Is it right?

Or are there some front-end frameworks that deal with authorization header?

Thank you for reading newbie'q question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to define a mechanism for sending the user's JWT back to the server. It's up to you to decide where the JWT will live in the request -- the most common places are in the `Authorization` header, or by setting a cookie on the browser (which will be sent along with every HTTP request). You should also consider whether you want the JWT to persist across sessions / page reloads (using for example `document.cookie` or `localStorage`).

If you choose not to use the cookie approach, you can configure all `$.ajax` requests to set your `Authorization` header "pre-flight" using [`$.ajaxSetup({...})`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) (but this is a bit of a sledge-hammer approach). Manually setting the `Authorization` header on each individual `$.ajax` request, as you've demonstrated above, is a good option too.

If you want to skip headers all together, you can send the JWT inside the body of your request (as JSON, for example).

Comment: Thank you so much. You solved my question perfectly!